# PostgreSQL UPDATE from JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

so i have two tables like this

**TableA :**

```
|  id  | name  | src  |
-----------------------
|   1  | T100  | B001 |
|   2  | T100  | B002 |
|   3  | T100  | B003 |
|   4  | T101  | B004 |
|   5  | T101  | B005 |
-----------------------
```

**TableB** :

```
| id | name | flag |
--------------------
| 1  | B001 |   1  |
| 2  | B002 |   1  |
| 3  | B003 |   1  |
| 4  | B004 |   1  |
| 5  | B005 |   1  |
--------------------
```

i want to update `flag` in `TableB` to `0` which used as `src` on `T100` in `TableA`

**TableB that i want after update :**

```
| id | name | flag |
--------------------
| 1  | B001 |   0  |
| 2  | B002 |   0  |
| 3  | B003 |   0  |
| 4  | B004 |   1  |
| 5  | B005 |   1  |
--------------------
```

here is my query

```
UPDATE TableB SET flag = 0
FROM TableB b INNER JOIN TableA a 
ON b.name = a.src
WHERE a.name = T100
```

but the result is, it updates all the `flag` to `0`, not just the `T100` sources

**TableB query result :**

```
| id | name | flag |
--------------------
| 1  | B001 |   0  |
| 2  | B002 |   0  |
| 3  | B003 |   0  |
| 4  | B004 |   0  |
| 5  | B005 |   0  |
--------------------
```

is something in my query that i do wrong or is there another way to solve this?
Thankyou

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) do **not** repeat the target table in the FROM clause.

Comment: `UPDATE TableB SET flag = 0
FROM  TableA a WHERE  b.name = a.src
AND a.name = 'T100';` (or: use exists())

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql-server?rq=1